# Get Value from nested JSON File in PHP with Placeholder

Tags: php, json, object, nested, placeholder

I want to write my own little translation function.

My JSON File looks like:

```
{
"start": {
  "body": {
    "headline": "Hello, world!"
   }
  }
}
```

In my PHP Frontend, i want to write just Placeholders for translated Strings. So id do

```
<h1><?php trans('start.body.headline'); ?></h1>
```

My PHP Function is simple and looks like:

```
function trans($string) {

    if (!isset($_GET['langID']))
        $lang = 'de';
    else
        $lang = $_GET['langID'];

    $str = file_get_contents('lang/'. $lang . '.json');
    $json = json_decode($str);
    $string = str_replace('.', '->', $string);
 
    echo $json->$string;

  }
```

But I don't get a Result.

The $string in My Function is correctly:

```
start->body->headline
```

And when I write:

```
echo $json->start->body->headline;
```

I get "Hello, world".

```
echo $json->$string;
```

is the same but doesn't work. why?

Answer (score 0):

becouse you are using the some variable name **$string** for function parameter , use the other variable name here.

```
$keyword = str_replace('.', '->', $string);

echo $json->{$keyword};
```

also you can use **return** method

```
function trans($string) {

if (!isset($_GET['langID']))
    $lang = 'de';
else
    $lang = $_GET['langID'];

$str = file_get_contents('lang/'. $lang . '.json');
$json = json_decode($str);
$keyword = str_replace('.', '->', $string);

return $json->{$keyword};
}
```

and than use short way of **echo** in html

```
<h1><?= trans('start.body.headline'); ?></h1>
```